# CSV formatting in batch files

Tags: windows, regex, sed

I have a **CSV** file with many lines in it like:

> "wmiprvse.exe","3596","Console","0","5,632 K","Running","NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE","0:00:00","N/A"

and want to change those lines to:

> wmiprvse.exe,NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE,N/A

**What's the best way to do it?**

---

I've the following (using [**cat** and **sed**](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/)) so far:

```
cat myfile | sed -e "1,2d;s/\"*//g;s/,.*,.*,.*,.*,.*,\(.*\),.*,\(.*\)/,\1,\2/"
```

But it doesn't work properly, any advices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you use `awk`?

As pointed out by wilhelmtell and Colin, replacing every space by a comma is not the right way because it also replaces the spaces in a string like `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE`

Use this instead

```
$ cat temp | awk 'BEGIN{FS = ","}{print $1","$8","$10}' | sed 's/"//g'
wmiprvse.exe,NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE,N/A
```

---

[Old answer]

```
$ cat temp | awk 'BEGIN{FS = ","}{print $1, $8, $10}' | sed 's/"//g'|
  sed 's/ /,/g'

wmiprvse.exe,NT,AUTHORITY\NETWORK,SERVICE,N/A
```

1.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS = ","}{print $1, $8, $10}'
```

print column number 1, 8 and 10

2.

```
sed 's/"//g'
```

remove `"`

3.

```
sed 's/ /,/g'
```

replace space by a `,`

Comment: The problem with this pipeline is that it removes all quotes and commas, regardless of their context. For instance, this pipeline will corrupt the line `"commas (,)","quotes (\")"`

Comment: You can change your print into `print $1","$8","$10}` , the second `sed` won't be necessary.

Comment: This will not work as there is a comma that works as a thousand delimiter. It may or may not be there.

Answer (score 1):

If you can have (escaped) quotes or commas in values then regular expressions are not the right tool for the job. You will need a designated state-machine for this. Your best bet is to write a small script with Ruby, Python, Perl or the likes.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use `awk` for this:

```
[jkramer/sgi5k:~]# cat foo
"wmiprvse.exe","3596","Console","0","5,632 K","Running","NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE","0:00:00","N/A"
[jkramer/sgi5k:~]# awk -F'","|"' '{print $2 "," $8 "," $10}' foo
wmiprvse.exe,NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE,N/A
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the thousand-delimiter comma. I would use cut/paste to split the file:

"wmiprvse.exe","3596","Console","0","5,632 K","Running","NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE","0:00:00","N/A"

cat myfile | cut -d'"' -f2,14,18 | paste -d','

It cuts fields 2,14 and 18 taking " as a separator and then pastes them together with comma as a separator

Answer (score 0):

Get your *nix tools from GNU win32 [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html). They are more updated. The more appropriate tool for this job is gawk, not sed. If you look at that massive regular expression, you will understand what i mean.

```
gawk "{print $1,$7}" file
```

Note, windows cmd.exe doesn't like double quotes. So if you are printing inside gawk and needs double quotes, always escape them, eg

```
gawk "{print \"hello\" }" file
```